# Unity "Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, this error (title) keeps popping up, and I don't know why. Its probably something simple, but I cant see it. Here is the code, I will mark what the error is referring to.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScoreCalculator : MonoBehaviour {

    public int[8] finalScore = new int[8]; // it's the first "]" here

    public void IncreaseMyScore (int increaseAmount, int forLevel) {
        finalScore[forLevel] += increaseAmount;
    }

    public void IncreaseByOne (int forLevel) {
        IncreaseMyScore(1, forLevel);
    }

    public void IncreaseByTwo (int forLevel) {
        IncreaseMyScore(2, forLevel);
    }

    public void IncreaseByThree (int forLevel) {
        IncreaseMyScore(3, forLevel);
    }

    public void IncreaseByFour (int forLevel) {
        IncreaseMyScore(4, forLevel);
    }

    public void SaveMyScores () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("FinalScore"+i,finalScore[i]);
    }
}
```

That break is not there in the code, just there to show what the error is referring to. Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like you have some formatting mixed in with your code - can you make sure that the code shown _exactly_ matches what you have?

Comment: The proper declaration would be `public int[] finalScore = new int[8];`  take out the `8` from the type declaration.  If that fixes it I will close this question as a typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

Array *types* do not have sizes.  `int[]` is a type; `int[8]` doesn't make sense.

Remove the number.

Comment: Alright I will try that, I posted a question earlier and the guy who answered told me to put "8" in there.